# WCF Explanation

Tags: c#, wcf

I've been working with the 3CX Phone System Phone API for a little while now. My goal is to get an application I designed to perform some of the tasks that the soft phone client does. I've been searching on the web for assistance with this API but have found very little.

I came across a post on github by another person who works with the API. In the repositiory is his entire solution. He explains that he uses WCF to communicate between the softphone and his application. Here is the post - https://github.com/TrickUK/3CX-Another-CRM. I've tried adapting this solution to my own but with no luck. I believe the WCF part of the solution is holding me back.

Please will someone give me a brief walkthrough of how to work with WCF?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should get you started: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/06/introduction-to-wcf-wcf-tutorial-wcf.html

Comment: If I make a comparison between this tutorial and the solution posted on GitHub, it seems the post is incomplete. He has 2 Interface Services and 1 class, which inherits neither interface. Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: This walkthrough helped a lot - https://web.archive.org/web/20141027055124/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication